# Stuck trying to figure out what to do next with this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've never programmed before but I've been slowly learning over the past week. I've created a form that basically allows my clan members to fill out some information and then upon submission it creates itself into it's own thread and names itself for me. It works perfect. The code is located just below.

```
<form id='generic_form'>
<div class='category'>

<table class='cat_head'>
<tr>
<td><h2 style='text-align:center'>Recruiting Form</h2></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id='form_spec'>
<tr>
<th colspan='2'><h2>Please fill out the fields below:</h2></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Recruits Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Does The Teamspeak Name & In Game Name Match?:</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>No</option>
<option>Yes</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Where Did They Come From?:</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>Warframe Recruitment Chat</option>
<option>Facebook Group</option>
<option>Friend of a Current Member</option>
<option>Warframe Forums</option>
<option>Returning Member</option>
<option>Teamspeak -Clan Transfer</option>
<option>Stream Recruitment</option>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Additional comments(things we should be aware of ex, no mic, under 15yrs, attitude etc):</td>
<td><textarea rows='3'></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan='2' id='send_form'><button type='submit'>Submit</button></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>

<style type='text/css'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
#form_spec tr td:first-child {
font-weight: bold;
width: 30%;
}
#form_spec input, #form_spec textarea {
width: 500px;
}
/* ]]> */
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var form_script = {
    form_id: $('#generic_form'),
    status_id: $('#send_form'),
    specific_id: $('#form_spec'),
    enable_guests: false,
    pm: {
    enabled: false, // Does not work for guests
    user: "ImMrBloo", // 1 user only
    title: "New Form From {{user_name}}",
    content: "{{form}}"
},
    topic: {
    enabled: true,
    forum_id: 5027801, // 1 id only
    title: "{{user_name}} Recruited Someone",
    description: "",
    content: "{{form}}"
},
    statuses: {
    not_logged_in: "You must be registered and signed in to use this feature.", // Used if enable_guests: false
    first: "Coagulating data...",
    second: "Sending form...",
    done: "Form sent!"
},
    submission_formatting: {
    separator: ' ',

    before_all: '',
    after_all: '',

    before_question: '[b][color=yellow]',
    after_question: '[/b][/color]',

    before_response: '[i]',
    after_response: '[/i]'
},
    possible_elements: 'input, textarea, select' // For the second column of table; .val() must work on it
};
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://z3.ifrm.com/313/104/0/p366373/form_script.js'></script>






<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
var rURL = 'http://s15.zetaboards.com/Panzerfaust/forum/5027801/';

form_script.form_id.submit(function () {
form_script.form_id.after('<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; font-style: italic; font-weight: 700">Redirecting you in 5 seconds...</div>');
window.setTimeout(function () {
location.href = rURL;
}, 5000);
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
</div></div><div id="foot_wrap"><table cellspacing="0" id="foot">
<tr>
<td id="foot_themechooser"><form action="http://s15.zetaboards.com/Panzerfaust/index/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="r" value="pages/recruitingform%2F" /><input type="hidden" name="r2" value="78be5b909814b66d9d88ca275b1a9703" /><label for="setskin">Choose a theme:</label> <select name='setskin' id='setskin' >
<option value='1207524' selected="selected">1: PSO (No width limit)</option>
<option value='1207535'>Mobile</option>
<option value='1215962'>Shapes Red</option>
</select>

 <button type="submit" id="btn_setskin">Change</button></form></td>
<td id="foot_links">

</td>
<td id="foot_datetime">
<a href='http://s15.zetaboards.com/Panzerfaust/home/?c=4' title='Change Time Settings'><img src='http://z5.ifrm.com/30160/63/0/p1167159/clock.png' alt='Time:' /> 10:59 PM Nov 13</a>
</td>
</tr>`
```

this code does work as intended. What I'd like to add is the answer to the first question of the form in the code below

```
<tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Recruits Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' /></td>
</tr>
```

and have the answer appear in the Description: "", line below. 
So when a thread is made it would say user name and in description the recruits name. From what I understand all I need to do is echo the first answer or something but I don't know how. If you have any knowledge or know how to implement this correctly. I'd be in your debt. Thanks.

```
 topic: {
enabled: true,
forum_id: 5027801, // 1 id only
title: "{{user_name}} Recruited Someone",
description: "",
content: "{{form}}"
```

Comment: give your input an unique id and do this: `topic.discription = $('#myInputId').val()`

Comment: where would I place this in the code? Also what do you mean by unique id? Do I make up some numbers? Sorry I'm still lost :( could you explain it a little bit. Both because I still don't understand what to do but also because I want to learn.

I understand to copy/paste what you have. I'm not sure where to place it in the code and as for the unique id part I'm not sure. How does this repeat the first answer and place it in the description portion :o

Comment: I've read it back over like 10 times @KevinKloet 
am I giving a unique id to the 
<td><input type='text' /></td> line
if so where would I place the id numbers on the line, could you give an example?

and still however stuck on where i would place your code response in my code.

Comment: `<input type='text' id="myInputId" />` and as the previous code should go in an `onsubmit` event for your form.

Comment: <tr>
<td style="color: yellow;">Recruits Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' id="32"/></td>
</tr>

works good and doesn't break the script. However wherever I place your other code the script doesn't go anymore. Could you show me where in my code it goes? :(

Comment: here i have made a little example: [example](http://codepen.io/kevin_kloet/pen/vyyLzz)

Comment: it didn't work for me :( Are you able to use my exact code above and plug in to see if it works? I'm starting to think the website is too finicky and won't do it no matter what :(

Comment: only the external form_script.js is giving error's now. here is what i got for the part you have given me. [here](http://codepen.io/kevin_kloet/pen/wooGqG)

Comment: hmm it didn't work still :(

Comment: define not working.

Comment: it spaghetti coded on the screen :(. Is there anyway I could get you to look at my site and see for yourself?

Comment: you could post a link to a verifiable/complete example of the website, i'll take a look after my break.

Comment: still no use with this code :(

Comment: what do you mean with no use, what do you expect it to do what it doesn't do?